# Sort by count SQL reporting services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a simple query in a tabloid control that gets all the leads in one month. I then use the tabloid control to group them into lead source. And then I have an associated count column. I want to sort my report on the count descending, without doing it in the query. I keep getting an error saying you cannot sort on an aggregate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one more thing..
just write your query in subquery part and write order by clause in outer query.

(suppose you have group by query as follow-

```
select lead_source, count(*) cnt
from your_table 
group by lead_source
```

)

so you can do as follow -

```
select lead_source, cnt from (
    select lead_source, count(*) cnt
    from your_table 
    group by lead_source
    )
order by cnt
```

this your_table and group by column list you have to edit accordingly your table structure ..

Comment: As a matter of fact, you don't need to use a subquery, you could add `order by cnt` to the original query and it would work just as well. Anyway, I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants, as they specifically said they didn't want to sort the rows in the query.

Comment: Well, you can do "order by count(*)" in the original query.  Whether or not you can do "order by cnt" depends on the database, and is not supported in SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It is, actually. The `ORDER BY` clause is [processed at a later stage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx "SELECT (Transact-SQL)") than the `SELECT` clause, so column aliases are accessible there. And [here's an illustration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/767bc/2).

Comment: Andriy, you are correct.  There are some versions of databases that haven't supported it in the past, but it appears that the standard is to allow aliases in order by.